# Give a certain example of an irreducible representation $V$.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

Give an example of an irreducible representation $V$ of a finite group $G$ and a $G-$automorphism $T:V\to V$ that is not scalar multiplication.

This is a short question I encountered when I self-learn group representation, which I have no clue to construct such representation, is there any uniform procedure to think about this kind of question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do this if your ground field is algebraically closed. This is
essentially Schur's lemma. But you can do it over $\Bbb R$. Let $G$
be cyclic of order $4$, with generator $a$. Then $G$ acts irreducibly on $\Bbb R^2$
with $a$ acting as the matrix
$$A=\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}.$$
Then we can take $T=A$.